# FPDF in PHP, setX just indents first row

Tags: php, text, textbox, fpdf

I use FPDF to creat PDF from PHP and i have a problem with the Write() function

i use the following code and i want to indent the text block not just the first row:

```
$pdf->SetX(60);
$pdf->Write(5,'' . str_repeat( ' This is a test of setX.', 30 ));
```

but as you can understand it's just indents the first row, any idea on how to move the whole text mas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One solution is to use MultiCell insted of Write:

```
$pdf->SetX(60);    
$pdf->MultiCell(60, 6, '' . str_repeat( ' This is a test of setX.', 30 ));
```